# database date = todays date

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to select data from mySQL database which was inserted today, however this query is working but it is returning 0 results. There is one row in my database which should be returned. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

$sql = "SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE DATE (date)= CURDATE()";

Comment: what is in your database field ? Share that one and result of the query .

Comment: what the field type of `date` in your table?

Comment: One big problem in this statement is the space between the name of the function and the opening paren. There can't be any space characters between those.  Ref: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/function-resolution.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/function-resolution.html). Also note that wrapping a column in a function disables MySQL's ability to make effective use of an index to satisfy the query. We prefer to reference a "bare" column, and do whatever contortions are required on the constant (evaluated once) side, even if that means doing two comparisons for a range scan.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that, unless you need milisecond information, you always store date information in [Unix Timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/). It is lighter to store, since it is only a integer value, is faster to retrieve and is universal, since it is always based on UTC.

Specially in PHP, converting date information to ([`time()`](http://php.net/time) and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime)) and from ([`date()`](http://php.net/date)) a unix timestamp is pretty easy. This way no matter where your user is, you can always show correct information in local time with almost no effort.

In your case you can calculate de timestamp for today 0 AM an today 12PM and then look for it in MySQL as:

`` $sql = "SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE `date`>{$dayStart}" AND `date`<{$dayEnd}; ``

Answer (score 2):

That would really depend on the actual datatype of the `date` column in `main_table`, how that column is defined, and whats stored in that column.

If that column is MySQL `DATE` datatype, then

```
    WHERE date = DATE(NOW())
```

If that column is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype, then

```
    WHERE date >= DATE(NOW()) AND date < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If that column is CHAR or VARCHAR, then it depends on the actual values stored. If that's stored in format 'mm/dd/yyyy' -- i.e. two digit month and two digit day (with leading zero) and four digit year, separated by slashes -- then

```
    WHERE date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Either u can use direct mysql date function or php date functions..Now I am using php function

```
$today = date('Y-m-d'); //To get the Current date as 2014-10-12

$sql = "SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE `date` = '$today'";
```

Since your column name is date (Same as that of DATE function in sql) use `date` ..``

Comment: It's true that MySQL reserved words used as identifiers need to be escaped, either by enclosing them in backticks, or qualifying them with a table name or table alias. But **`DATE`** is not on the [**MySQL Reserved Words list**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). The effectiveness of this query to return the specified rows really depends on the actual datatype of the `date` column in `main_table`, and what values are actually stored. If `date` is MySQL DATE datatype, then equality comparison to string literal in format 'YYYY-MM-DD' would be appropriate.